# How do make txt based keyword extractor on pandas dataframe with `other` as exception handler more effectively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I make txt based keyword extractor on pandas dataframe with `other` as exception handler, but the code seems to long. Here's my dataset

```
id  description
1   description: kartu debit 20/10 indomaretcipete r
4   description: biaya adm
15  description: tarikan atm 14/10
20  description: trsf ws269b100420/home credit 0372540
22  description: kartu debit 09/10 starbuckspasaraya
```

Here's the txt file named `text.txt`

```
indomaret
starbucks
home credit
```

Here's my code

```
with open('text.txt') as f: 
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content ]
def ambil(inp):
    try:
        out = []
        for x in content:      
            if x in inp:
                out.append(x)
        if len(out) == 0:
            return 'other'
        else:
            output = ' '.join(out)
            return output
    except:
        return 'other'

df['keyword'] = df['description'].apply(ambil)
```

Here's the output

```
id  description                                         keyword
1   description: kartu debit 20/10 indomaretcipete r    indomaret
4   description: biaya adm                              other
15  description: tarikan atm 14/10                      other
20  description: trsf ws269b100420/home credit 0372540  home credit
22  description: kartu debit 09/10 starbuckspasaraya    starbucks
```

I wan to my code shorter with existing pandas function, how suppose to do date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
df['keyword'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in content if i in x]))
df['keyword'].fillna('other', inplace=True)
```